# RegEx engine works slowly with this Regular expression, please see?

Tags: c#, regex, keypress

I'm trying to suppress any input from user if the content of the textbox seems not to be an valid email address. This is not a check after user types and leaves the textbox, this checks right when user typing and suppress the input if it looks like the text is going to be invalid email address. For example, when user types 'ilove.net', this is known as the first part of a valid email address (so everything is still OK at the moment), now if user types '@', again, the text is still OK for the first part of an email address. But if user types '@' next, this will be recognized as an invalid email address no matter what user types after this second '@' and so that input would be suppressed.

Here is my first try:

```
RegEx regEx = new RegEx(@"^(?!(\d|\s|-|[.]))([^.-]*[.]?[^. -]+)+@([^-. ]+[.][^-. ]+)+(?<=\D)$");
string basicSampleEmailAddress = "xxx@x.x";
private void textEmail_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e){
    string current = textBoxEmail.Text.Insert(textBoxEmail.SelectionStart,e.KeyChar.ToString());
    bool matchable = false;
    for(int i = basicSampleEmailAddress.Length-1; i >= 0; i--){
        if(regEx.IsMatch(string.Format("{0}{1}",current,basicSampleEmailAddress.Substring(i))) { matchable=true; break;}
    }
    e.Handled = !matchable;
}
```

This seems to work OK when I type the first 5-7 characters into the textEmail (TextBox), however the 'slow processing' can be seen when I type next characters, and even If I type fast, my application becomes frozen processing something (I think it relates to RegEx), the CPU usage is about 20% and the form title  is appended with a text 'Not responding'. In fact, I can't make it normal once it turns to such a frozen state. I have to stop the application through VS Studio.

Now, I've tried another expression and everything works OK:
The code is all the same to the above except that I change the Regular expression to this one:

```
regEx = new Regex(@"(?i)^[0-9a-z_]{3,}((\.[0-9a-z]+)+)?@[a-z]+(\.[a-z0-9]+)+$");
```

That means, the problem is caused by the expression in the first try. I would like to know why it was too slow when working with the first expression? Since the day I've known of RegEx and fell in love with it, I thought RegEx is something very fast and the speed almost depends on the input string, not much depends on the expression.

Your help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: usual solution: start timer on typing stops, reset timer on each keypress, after say 800ms timer fires, and runs that code...

Comment: I don't want to use timer, and in fact it is now OK with my second expression. I would like to know what's wrong with the first so that the RegEx was too slow. Thanks!

Comment: Be careful with email regex's, they are very hard to get correct. For example, your second regex incorrectly says that `foo+bar@buz.com` is not a valid email address, when it is.

Comment: @MattGreer thank you for the correction of the email reg expression, but it's not the fact explaining why the first is too slow. I'll correct my expression, just plus some invalid characters will solve such a problem...

Comment: even the code in my question doesn't allow control characters such as arrow characters, backspace...

Comment: @MattGreer I've just rethought of your suggestion about using timer, I wonder how that timer can help suppress the user input right when s/he typing???? If it can, maybe it's good to try. (I like multi-solutions to a problem). Thanks!

Comment: @MitchWheat made that suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by this portion `([^.-]*[.]?[^. -]+)+` (before the `@` sign). Given an input `something@invalid--gar..bage`, there are multiple ways for `something@invalid` to fit in the sub-pattern `([^.-]*[.]?[^. -]+)+` during backtracking. There is nothing surprising here. Since `[^. -]+` can match `@`, the engine will just chuck forward, then backtrack later.

Below shows the successful attempts at matching `something@invalid` against `([^.-]*[.]?[^. -]+)+` when backtracking from failed match:

```
(something@invali [empty] d)
(something@inval [empty] id)
(something@inval [empty] i) ([empty] [empty] d)
(something@inva [empty] lid)
(something@inva [empty] li) ([empty] [empty] d)
(something@inva [empty] l) (i [empty] d)
(something@inva [empty] l) ([empty] [empty] id)
(something@inva [empty] l) ([empty] [empty] i) ([empty] [empty] d)
(something@inv [empty] alid)
...
```

`()` is text match by each iteration of `([^.-]*[.]?[^. -]+)+`, the 3 parts inside `()` correspond to text matched by `[^.-]*`, `[.]?` and `[^. -]+`.

As you can see, the engine is doing useless backtracking work here. The problem is that you allow too many way for the engine to backtrack when there is no match. Notice that:

- `[^.-]*[.]?[^. -]+` can give `n` ways to retry on a matching substring with length `n`.

  For example: `(something@invali [empty] d)`, `(something@inval [empty] id)`, `(something@inva [empty] lid)`, ...
- And the fact that the whole thing is repeated doesn't help, since you have 2<sup>n</sup> ways to split the matching substring of length n into repetitions.

  For example:

  - 1 group: `(something@invalid)`
  - 2 groups: `(something@inval) (id)` or `(something@invali) (d)` or `(someth) (ing@invalid)`

Comment: I must admit that the first expression of mine is something like a demo to test, it even couldn't filter for correct email addresses, the problem looks like what you explained. Thanks for your help!